# In IBM Maximo, How to create a new custom application under Administration > Resources Module

Tags: maximo

I have created a new application and i was able to put it under the administration module by using the module as 'SETUP' while creating the application. But i want to move this application under the Resouces module which is the sub-module under Administration, so that  my new application would be along Person, Person group applications group.

Answer (score 0):

Module and submodules are maintained in the MaxMenu table.

In this specific case
If you run this query,

```
select * from maxmenu where position = '10041' and headerdescription='Resources'
```

you can see the position is 10041 for the sub module Resources which is under the SETUP module.
All i need to do is, once the application is created under a module, we just neeed to update position and subposition columns to the desired value of the sub modules.
note: Update the subposition first,since by default it is having the value 0, if you update the position first, you will get unique constraint error. so check the max subposition value for that position. like

```
select max(subposition) from maxmenu where position = '10041'
```

Once you update the position and subposition in the database, restart the jvms and you will see the application is now moved to the desired sub-folder.

Comment: Don't forget the moduleapp column. You'll want to change it from SETUP to whatever the Resources module code is. (Arun PM's first query will return that in the KEYVALUE column.)